# В чем причина ошибки?

Tags: python

> `Error: rlm_python:EXCEPT:<class '_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError'>: (2006, 'MySQL     server has gone away')`

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.0.1.1",user="111",passwd="111",db="111")
cursor = db.cursor()

def mac_search(*args):
    serid=[465,641,465,641,638,637,644,645,648,709,1022,1120,1122,1124]
    sql = """SELECT sl2.service_id FROM ip_groups AS ig \
            JOIN iptraffic_service_links AS isl ON ig.ip_group_id=isl.ip_group_id \
            JOIN service_links AS sl ON isl.id=sl.id \
            JOIN accounts AS ac ON sl.account_id=ac.id \
            JOIN service_links AS sl2 ON ac.id=sl2.account_id \
            WHERE ig.mac='%s' \
            AND ig.is_deleted=0 \
            AND isl.is_deleted=0 \
            AND sl.is_deleted=0 \
            AND ac.is_deleted=0 \
            AND sl2.is_deleted=0;""" %args[0].split()[0]
    cursor.execute(sql)
    for j1 in cursor.fetchall():
        if j1[0] in serid:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM s_multicast WHERE service_id=%s AND %s>=ip_start AND %s<=ip_end;" %(j1[0],args[0].split()[1],args[0].split()[1]))
            return cursor.fetchone()

def authorize(p):
    mac = "{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}".format(p[0][1][1:-1][:2],p[0][1][1:-1][2:4],p[0][1][1:-1][4:6],p[0][1][1:-1][6:8],p[0][1][1:-1][8:10],p[0][1][1:-1][10:12]).lower()
    ipm = "{0}".format(struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(p[8][1]))[0])
    data = "{0} {1}".format(mac,ipm)
    start = time.time()
    g = mac_search(data)
    print "!!!Elapsed Time: %.4f" %(time.time() - start)
    if g:
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK
    else:
        accounting(p)
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_REJECT

def accounting(p):
    if p[8][0] == 'Acct-Status-Type':
        sql = """INSERT INTO s_multicast_log (mac,sw_ip,port,channel,date,status) VALUES ('%s','%s',%d,'%s',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'2')""" %(p[0][1][1:-1],p[1][1],int(p[6][1]),p[7][1])
    else:
        sql = """INSERT INTO s_multicast_log (mac,sw_ip,port,channel,date,status) VALUES ('%s','%s',%d,'%s',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'0')""" %(p[0][1][1:-1],p[2][1],int(p[7][1]),p[8][1])
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK
    except:
        db.rollback()
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_FAIL

def post_auth(p):
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP
```

Из-за чего может быть вызвана данная ошибка?

Comment: скорее всего сервер выключен или недоступен.

Comment: Вот-вот, написано же, что сервер ушел погулять:  

    'MySQL     server has gone away'

Comment: Вижу что написано, база работающая боевая.

Comment: Не. Питон так пишет отнюдь не потому, что сервера нет :))

Какая-то ошибка в запросе. Но поскольку автор не указал, на каком именно запросе падает, да какая у него структура таблиц, пусть угадывает сам.

Comment: На первом запросе уже падает в функции mac_search, тут места не хватит показать структуры таблиц.

Comment: Вручную запрос проверяли?

Comment: все запросы работают, тестировал  не один день, дал нагрузку, вылезли ошибки. Отрабатывал sql запросы на быстродействие все ok. Может где нужно закрывать соединение db.close()

Comment: Четыре джойна могут дать плохой план выполнения, который под нагрузкой заставит запрос выполняться слишком долго. Соединение вылетит по таймауту и тогда привет — 2006, server has gone away.<br/><br/>Был у меня такой случай, на щапросе с 6 левыми джойнами. Рещил, разбив запрос на два.

Comment: Ошибка выходи в функции def accounting(p):
даже с join работает.

Comment: «Server has gone away» означает, что клиент пытается делать запросы на закрытом соединении. Включите со стороны MySQL-сервера логгирование всего и вся (от запросов до коннектов-дисконнектов), и посмотрите что происходит.

И вообще, это плохой подход. Один коннект на весь RADIUS, плюс, один раз сеть икнула, коннект порвался и все. Правильная архитектура тут — пул соединений и т.д..

И еще. Кто-нибудь, сделайте меня развидеть это: `mac = "{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}".format(p[0][1][1:-1][:2],p[0][1][1:-1][2:4],p[0][1][1:-1][4:6],p[0][1][1:-1][6:8],p[0][1][1:-1][8:10],p[0][1][1:-1][10:12]).lower()`

Answer (score 2):

«Server has gone away» означает, что клиент пытается делать запросы на закрытом/дохлом соединении. Включите со стороны MySQL-сервера логгирование всего и вся (от запросов до коннектов-дисконнектов), и посмотрите что происходит.

Хотя, вообще, все написанное — это плохой подход, который, совершенно неудивительно что падает. Т.е., у меня сильное подозрение, что падает все с клиентской (FreeRADIUS'а) стороны, из-за проблем с тредами, благо симптомы (один тестовый клиент — работает, боевой трафик — дохнет) характерны. Тут даже не одно соединение на весь RADIUS-сервер (для любой приличной нагрузки этого мало же!), а один курсор. Что, в общем-то, не thread-safe. Два запроса параллельно пришли и все. А в документации на MySQLdb написано даже больше:

> The MySQL protocol can not handle multiple threads using the same connection at once. Some earlier versions of MySQLdb utilized locking to achieve a threadsafety of 2. While this is not terribly hard to accomplish using the standard Cursor class (which uses mysql_store_result()), it is complicated by SSCursor (which uses mysql_use_result(); with the latter you must ensure all the rows have been read before another query can be executed. It is further complicated by the addition of transactions, since transactions start when a cursor execute a query, but end when COMMIT or ROLLBACK is executed by the Connection object. Two threads simply cannot share a connection while a transaction is in progress, in addition to not being able to share it during query execution. This excessively complicated the code to the point where it just isn't worth it.
>
> The general upshot of this is: **Don't share connections between threads.** It's really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end, will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like **cache connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a time**. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, **the MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die**. You have been warned.
>
> For threaded applications, try using a connection pool. This can be done using the Pool module.

(Выделение мое, суть — не разделяйте соединения между тредами. Запихайте коннекты в пул и отдавайте тредам по одному на момент времени. Иначе клиентская библиотека MySQL подавится и умрет. Остальное переводить лень, извините.)

Правильная архитектура тут — пул соединений, который, во-первых, держит несколько (какое-то фиксированное число, или адаптивно меняя размер под нагрузкой — зависит от реализации) открытых сессий, и по запросу берет свободную из пула. Курсоры создавать уже в функциях. Или брать Pool из MySQLdb Если не хочется изобретать свой велосипед — тот же [пул коннектов из SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/pooling.html) [в помощь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98687/what-is-the-best-solution-for-database-connection-pooling-in-python/98703#98703) или [PySQLPool](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlpool/), как вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, вроде все получилось!